# How to setup whatsapp account on second sim without alerting whatsapp contacts of first sim?

Tags: samsung, whatsapp-messenger, dual-sim

My phone is [Samsung F41 Galaxy](https://www.samsung.com/in/smartphones/galaxy-z/galaxy-f41-blue-64gb-sm-f415fzbdins/). It allows to use dual sim.

But I don't want to merge two whatsapp accounts of dual sim. So how to setup whatsapp account on second sim **without alerting whatsapp contacts of first sim**?

Second sim is for **office purpose**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the "Insular" from F-Droid.

https://f-droid.org/en/packages/com.oasisfeng.island.fdroid/

It activates the Android feature called "Work Profile", (which is essentially a different user account), and lets you install app copies into it. You can control what data are shared between those two profiles.

In principle, that is also doable with console command `pm` , but is much more tedious.

Also, there is a feature of certain ROMs, such as OnePlus, which has this feature built in. (But it uses a different user ID, so you can have three copies of an app  within a single GUI, one default, one in Insular, and one  in an OnePlus "parallel app".)

The downside of this is that TWRP backups (nandroid) will  not work. You can use Titanium Backup, or just do the backups manually.